# how to publish a node content to the walll of a Facebook account?

Tags: nodes, social-network

Just wondering if is there any module to let publish a node content (title, body and images) to the wall of a Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

check [Fridge](http://drupal.org/project/fridge) for a fast solution. wont post the whole content, though. (and i wonder how that would be done)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) for this.

> With Drupal for Facebook, you can harness all the power of Drupal in
>   you Facebook App. If you already have content in Drupal, you can
>   expose it on Facebook.

The documentation is [here](http://drupal.org/node/195035).

> **What can Drupal for Facebook help you do?**
>
> - Add Like buttons, and other social plugins to your Drupal-powered website.
> - Let users authenticate to your site using their facebook username and password. This saves the user the trouble of registering with your
>     site, and allows you to build additional social features, known as
>     Facebook Connect.
> - Create applications on facebook.com. Powered by your Drupal server, these applications add features and content for your users while they
>     visit facebook.com.
> - Publish content from your site to a user's Facebook stream (wall).
> - And more!

Comment: did you try it? Will I be able to post in the Wall the title, body and images for a given node? The Fridge module just allows to put a link to the node (no images, nor the body of the node)

Comment: I'm not going to lie, it's been a while since I've used it (last time was on D6 in 2011) so I can't really offer any more advice.  Sorry :(

Comment: @chefnelone i think you will have to specify properly what sort of "post" you mean ... when you add a link, you can add "some" content and 1 image. or did you think of creating notes for example ?

Comment: Let say I create a new node, this node has a title, a body and 1 image. I just need to put a new note in the Wall, this note will contain those 3 fields (title, body and image)

Comment: I just enable the Drupal for Facebook module, but I find it a little complicated, the documentation says nothing about Streaming. Any tutorial out there?